# Trading view wont show results

Tags: pine-script, forex

I just started using pine-script 2 days ago trying to code a trading strategy I found on Youtube. I finished it but it wont show the results for the back test. I took the William's alligator and ema straight from trading view. I know my code probably looks horrendous but can someone point out where I can make changes and improve the code. Thank you!

for reference the strategy rules for a long position are price above 600 period ema, price dip into vwap, and wait for close in-between the lips and teeth of William's alligator

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at 
https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © todamoon32

//@version=4
strategy("stragety numbero uno","SNU", overlay = true)

//williams alligator
smma(src, length) =>
    smma =  0.0
    smma := na(smma[1]) ? sma(src, length) : (smma[1] * (length - 1) + src) / length
    smma
jawLength = input(13, minval=1, title="Jaw Length")
teethLength = input(8, minval=1, title="Teeth Length")
lipsLength = input(5, minval=1, title="Lips Length")
jawOffset = input(8, title="Jaw Offset")
teethOffset = input(5, title="Teeth Offset")
lipsOffset = input(3, title="Lips Offset")
jaw = smma(hl2, jawLength)
teeth = smma(hl2, teethLength)
lips = smma(hl2, lipsLength)
plot(jaw, "Jaw", offset = jawOffset, color=#2962FF)
plot(teeth, "Teeth", offset = teethOffset, color=#E91E63)
plot(lips, "Lips", offset = lipsOffset, color=#66BB6A)

// creation of ema
len = input(600, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, title="Source")
offset = input(title="Offset", type=input.integer, defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)
out = ema(src, len)
plot(out, title="EMA", color=color.red, offset=offset)

// price indicator
priceSMA = sma(close, 1)
plot(priceSMA)

// vwap
plot(vwap, color= color.yellow)

// long condition 
longcondition1 = out < priceSMA
longcondition2 = crossunder(priceSMA, vwap) 
longcondition3 = crossover(priceSMA,vwap)
longcondition4 = teethLength > close

// shortcondition
shortcondition1 = out > priceSMA
shortcondition2 = crossover(priceSMA,vwap)
shortcondition3 = crossunder(priceSMA,vwap)
shortcondition4 = teethLength < close

if(longcondition1 and longcondition2 and longcondition3 and longcondition4) 
    stopLoss = lowest(30)
    takeProfit = (close - lowest(30))*2 +close
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long,100,when = lipsLength <close)
    strategy.exit("exit", "long", stop=stopLoss, limit=takeProfit)

if(shortcondition1 and shortcondition2 and shortcondition3 and shortcondition4)
    strategy.entry("short", strategy.short,100,when= lipsLength > close )
    stopLoss = highest(30)
    takeProfit = (highest(30)-close)*2 -close
    strategy.exit("exit", "short", stop=stopLoss, limit=takeProfit)
```

Answer (score 1):

So we have a few problems here that will give you trouble and I attempted to get you passed them all so that you can keep working on what matters. I will list them and then give you some code so you can get on your way.

1. shortcon 2 and 3, longcon 2 and 3 both contradict each other as one is crossup and the other a down. We have these linked with "and" over our entries so both can never be true together. I slid an or in just to get by for now.
2. we should avoid using "when=" if we use an "if" or vice versa. (we could just use when or just use an if). This can help to avoid contradictory statements once again. (our whens also contradict as each is also the entry for the opposite pos)
3. our exit statements are under an if that only becomes true when our entry criteria is satisfied. This means our exit orders arent sent to the broker emulator until our long cond. become true again. We should place the exits under an if that is conditional to a position. (please see below)
4. our stop/target calcs are made under and if, which is good, but if we do not use "var" to save these levels, then they will calc on every bar, which we dont want. So we can declare them with "var" which allows us to "save" a variable, and then assign it conditionally under the entry if. So i just took the se calcs above and assigned them when our conds. are satisfied.
5. our stop/limit calcs are based on say 30 bars prior. This can create a situation in your strategy where your limits and stops are never calculated because at the first bars on the chart these levels returned "na" until there were 30 bars on the chart to calculate. We need to put in some kind of check to make sure this doesnt happen or we will get into a trade without a stop or a limit which means we never get out. I used the na() function, linked these together and added them to your entry if.
6. finally, we are setting our stops, limits under our entry if which is great now, but what if all the conds. are satisfied and we are already in a pos? Well then we assign our stops and limits again! Dont want that either. So I added a FLAT check to make sure we werent in a position when our conds were satisfied, which puts us in and sets our stops/limits at that time. Please note that these means we isolate our trades ie. have to be 0 position before entering. If we want to be able to go from long straight to short you would also need to add a check for that ie "and (FLAT or SHORT) and..."

I know thats a lot, so maybe just start with the 2 instances of the contradictory entry statements and go from there ;) I also added some PLOTS at the bottom that are conditional to your position so we can see where our levels are when in a pos! Heres the code:

```
 //@version=4
strategy("stragety numbero uno","SNU", overlay = true)

//williams alligator
smma(src, length) =>
    smma =  0.0
    smma := na(smma[1]) ? sma(src, length) : (smma[1] * (length - 1) + src) / length
    smma
jawLength = input(13, minval=1, title="Jaw Length")
teethLength = input(8, minval=1, title="Teeth Length")
lipsLength = input(5, minval=1, title="Lips Length")
jawOffset = input(8, title="Jaw Offset")
teethOffset = input(5, title="Teeth Offset")
lipsOffset = input(3, title="Lips Offset")
jaw = smma(hl2, jawLength)
teeth = smma(hl2, teethLength)
lips = smma(hl2, lipsLength)
plot(jaw, "Jaw", offset = jawOffset, color=#2962FF)
plot(teeth, "Teeth", offset = teethOffset, color=#E91E63)
plot(lips, "Lips", offset = lipsOffset, color=#66BB6A)

// creation of ema
len = input(600, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, title="Source")
offset = input(title="Offset", type=input.integer, defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)
out = ema(src, len)
plot(out, title="EMA", color=color.red, offset=offset)

// price indicator
priceSMA = sma(close, 1)
plot(priceSMA)

// vwap
plot(vwap, color= color.yellow)

// long condition 
longcondition1 = out < priceSMA
longcondition2 = crossunder(priceSMA, vwap) 
longcondition3 = crossover(priceSMA,vwap)
longcondition4 = teethLength > close

// shortcondition
shortcondition1 = out > priceSMA
shortcondition2 = crossover(priceSMA,vwap)
shortcondition3 = crossunder(priceSMA,vwap)
shortcondition4 = teethLength < close

FLAT = strategy.position_size == 0

var stopLoss = 0.0 
var takeProfit = 0.0

longTPcalc  = (close - lowest(30))*2 +close
shortTPcalc = close - (highest(30)-close)*2 

longstopcalc  = lowest(30)
shortstopcalc = highest(30)

NAcheck = na(longTPcalc) or na(shortTPcalc) or na(longstopcalc) or na(shortstopcalc)

if(longcondition1 and longcondition2 or longcondition3 and longcondition4) and FLAT and not NAcheck
    stopLoss := longstopcalc
    takeProfit := longTPcalc
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)
    
if strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit("exit", "long", stop=stopLoss, limit=takeProfit)

if(shortcondition1 and shortcondition2 or shortcondition3 and shortcondition4) and FLAT and not NAcheck
    strategy.entry("short", strategy.short)
    stopLoss := shortstopcalc
    takeProfit := shortTPcalc

if strategy.position_size < 0
    strategy.exit("exit", "short", stop=stopLoss, limit=takeProfit) 

plot(strategy.position_size != 0 ? stopLoss   : na, "Stop",  color.red,   style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(strategy.position_size != 0 ? takeProfit : na, "Limit", color.green, style=plot.style_linebr)
```

Cheers and good luck!

Comment: Thank you! One more question though, if I wanted to enter a trade once the close finishes in-between the the lips and teeth of Williams alligator a few candles after the other conditions are met how would I go about doing that.